# mostly garbage output from serial UART of microcomputer STM32F091RC on target board

Tags: serial-port, stm32, uart, mbed, stm32f0

Expected first printf line of software to serial output to Windows7 PC is:

> main()  **************************  SW START Project    2016-10-30 x1

Actual serial output (at TeraTerm or PuTTY);

> ▒▒▒▒()`j**j*j**j*j**j*j**j*j**j*j  ▒▒`Ӕ▒Ҕ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ `r01v-q0-30`▒q

Serial worked great from mbed or VisualGDB to NUCLEO evaluation board. 
ie.:

```
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
```

Now, I'm running VisualGDB to the actual target board with a STM32F091RC.
ie.:

```
Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX);
```

At 9600, some chars are correct, most are garbage.
I've tried alternate target and cables, same problem.  PC's Terminal program  (TeraTerm or PuTTY) set at 8,n,1.
Looked in mbed library; default config is 8 data, no parity, 1 stop.

USB/serial converter cable is:  FTDIChip TTL-232R-RPi   (normally for Raspberry Pi).

Comment: The software works with an evaluation board, and the same software doesn't work on a custom board. It looks like a problem with the board.

Comment: Assuming the 'failure' is repeatable, maybe the custom board has different divisor for the UART - have you tried changing the PC serial port baud rate up/down? You say 'default config is 8 data...' - perhaps on your custom board that default isn't being asserted - try asserting the serial data format.

Comment: Are you sure it's suppose to be 9600?  Generally when you get garbage but see some of the characters it's a baud rate issue.  Do you need hardware handshaking?

Comment: Did you checked that the crystal/clock source frequency in your NUCLEO evaluation board and Target board are same?

Answer (score 0):

It could be clock mismatch between eval board and target board. Assuming, you have correct grounding.
Another issue could be number of data bits in configs is off.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not relevant anymore, but you have to pay attention to this points.

- The Signal level is 3.3v and not 5v, not all USB Uart adapters work correctly with is
- The polarity is the inverted to the standard, i.e. start bit is 1.5bit low like here

[image: arm uart]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have correct parity and bits. Most people (and Arduino) use 8N1 by default, but STM32 sample code uses 7O1 by default. See here: https://community.st.com/thread/40340-stm32cubefwf2v140projectsstm32f207zg-nucleoexamplesuartuartprintf-printing-garbage-data-over-the-terminal